# Why is Black Widow so depressed in "Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, black-widow

Why is she so sad and depressed? I know half the world is gone, but she said Avengers was their family and her closest friends are still there, who does she miss? Nick Fury, Vision?

It's not like she lost some one close like Hawkeye did. She still had her closest Avengers family, she being so sad and depressed after five years is not believable.

So who did she lose that would make her feel like that?

Comment: “she being so sad and depressed after five years is not believable” — there's these things called human beings, and they're not actually super-predictable.

Comment: Even without the reasons mentioned in the other answers, "Billions of people are dead, I was part of the team that had the best chance to prevent it, and we failed," sounds like a believable reason to be depressed to me.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Golden Comment

Comment: So, half of all life dying and it being partially your fault is no longer a reason to be sad?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

She did lose someone, in a way. She was very close to Hawkeye, and they kind of drifted apart when he went rogue. When she meets him in the alley, she tells him something the following:

> **Clint Barton:** Don't give me hope.
>
> **Natasha Romanoff:** I'm sorry I couldn't give it to you sooner.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

meaning she tried (but likely failed) to appease him, and herself in the process.

And more than that, while she's being all workaholic, she also (like every other hero) lost half of the world. Thanos handed their butts to them, even when they all teamed up, Gods, guys in suits, superpowered individuals - and still they lost. And after that, when Thanos destroyed the Stones, there was *no* hope of everything, there was just no point.

After all the path she had walked in previous MCU movies, overcoming her doubts of not being an actual hero but a "monster" (because she had killed people), that double loss had a terrible toll on her - that's why her sacrifice for the Soul Stone is the end of her arc, the culmination of it, with her being an actual hero.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, she was close to Nick Fury and somewhat close to Maria Hill so having them be dusted must be hurting her. On top of that she lost, she tried her hardest to stop Thanos but lost so is feeling some guilt towards that and is sad about what happened. I mean 5 years is a very short amount of time to get over what actually happened, some people never get over 1 loss in their life, imagine half the population of the universe dying and how much that would affect you.

Also note that she was incredibly close to Clint's family with the children calling her auntie and them naming a child after her so that will be affecting her a lot too.

> **Natasha Romanoff:** How's little Natasha, huh?
>
> **Laura Barton:** She's…Nathaniel.
>
> **Natasha Romanoff:** Traitor.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

However, one of the biggest things that is affecting her is what Hawkeye has become. She does not like the rage and violence he is inflicting across the world. Just remember the scene where Rhodey tells her about Clint attacking people in Mexico and that's when she starts to tear up a lot.

Answer (score -1):

She asserts some kind of motherly position who not only was responsible for the death of her friends and the world, she was heartbroken that everything was gone, especially Hawkeye and his family. She has always battled a depressed mood throughout the movies by evident by her numerous statements that she was just a weapon built to destroy and fight, but especially when she talked about not being able to have children. After Thanos wipes out half the population and most importantly, her friends, she shows evidence that she feels responsibility and extreme love for them, as if she would her children. Hawkeye’s family meant the world to her and she was heatbroken they were gone but also that Hawkeye was hurting.